# Display the popular tags by default in the backend post edit page (without having to click on the link that displays them)

Tags: posts, admin, tags

I know there should be a way to call the AJAX function by page load but I've been looking at how to do this for hours and can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by bypassing the script.